# how find a number of specific sub-string in a string

Tags: java, regex

hi i'm starting to learn java but i have a problem with regex i have a string like this

> str = "int f ( int a , int b )"

i want to find how many "int" occured

i read in oracle's doc and i found that we have a regex called X{n} that told us for example if the "int" matches exactly n time or not
i write this code but it gives me false

```
 String temp = "int f ( int a , int b )";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bint{3}\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
        if(matcher.find()
        system.out.print("found");
```

any idea

Comment: the `X{n}` pattern looks for consecutive occurrences, your occurrences are not next to each other, hence the `false`. You need to use something a little more complex, like a combination substrings and `indexOf`.

Comment: Also you can use `int nb = StringUtils.countMatches(temp, "int");` from Apache Commons.

Comment: Is that occurrences of the individual word "int" or any occurrence of the letters "int"? For example, what's the expected result for str = "int f ( int myint , int winthis )" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
int numberOfOccurences = str.split("int", -1).length - 1;
```

The [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method of the String class splits the string into an array around the occurrences of the sub-string ("int", in this case).

Comment: Will definitely prefer design over efficiency. Great idea!

Comment: I checked it. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `find()` repeatedly on a `Matcher` to find repeated copies of the pattern. So, search for `/\bint\b/`, then count how many times `find()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int occurrences = 0;
int index = 0;

while (index < str.length() && (index = str.indexOf("int", index)) >= 0) {
    occurrences++;
    index += 3; //'length' of (characters in) 'int'
}
```

`Occurrences` holds the number you're after (i.e. the amount of times 'int' can be found in `str`).

Comment: did you mean `index += 3` instead?

Comment: I did indeed, thanks. I also meant 'int' instead of 'int a' (I mis-read the OP).

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood `X{N}`: It matches subsequent occurrences of the previous expression, so `a{3}` will match `aaa` but not `ababa`.

You should not use regular expressions for this task. They are just inefficient for counting occurrences.

```
int countOccurrences(String str, String what) {
  int index, n;
  index = n = 0;

  // Increase n as long as there are occurrences after the
  // last found index
  while(index < str.length() && (index = str.indexOf(what, index)) != -1) {
    n++;
    index += what.length();
  }

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

split() was my first guess, but there's a few special cases for it.  It ends up a little messy...

```
int count = (" " + str + " ").split(" int ").length-1;
```

Comment: length is a property of the array :) See my answer.

Comment: Though this works for the given **example**, it will fail for `int foo(int a)`.

Comment: You can't assume the "int foo(int a)" is valid input, spaces may be a required part of the language.  See my question to the OP.  "int foo( int myint )" could also be valid input, in which case my answer is the only correct one here.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use a complicated regex? You can check the String with `String#indexOf(int, int)` three times in a row - Regex are able to match expressions by using NFA and if you don't have non-determinism there's seldom use for regex in my opinion.